# Open Select Associated Content in Sitecore Page Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, page-editor

Our requirements require us to store page modules beneath page items in a Modules folder. In the renderings for modules, I have set the Datasource Location to be ./Modules. My page with modules structure is shown below.

page
  |
  --- Modules (folder)
        |
        --- module 1
        --- module 2
        --- module 3

When a module is added to a page via the Page Editor, and the Datasource Location is a normal path rather than a ./ in it, the Select Associated Content box should appear. It doesn't appear when the Datasource Location is './'.

Is there a way to force the 'Select Associated Content' to show up automatically? I do not want the user to see the Component Properties window either.

Thanks

Comment: So the window pops up for a regular path but not a query in Datasource Location? Do you have a Datasource Template selected?

Comment: Correct. Window pops up with regular path not query. Also, there is a template selected in Datasource Template.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path you are trying really exists. When the dialog does not appear is because there is no valid Datasource Location.

The field Datasource Location accept a path or Sitecore queries. You also can use multiple datasource separating the queries with pipe.

These are all valid values for the Ds Location.

```
/sitecore/content/Components/Rich Text

./modules

./ancestor-or-self::*/child::*[@@templatename='Modules']

/sitecore/content/Components/Rich Text|./modules
```

Also to improve yours google searchs, this kind of sublayout with datasources editable in Page Editor is called **Components**

.

**UPDATE:**

There is this processor in the `getRenderingDatasource` pipeline.

```html
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetRenderingDatasource.GetDatasourceLocation, Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

You may want to go there and substitute it by a custom class where you can debug, and check the get item(). 
Only when the program reachs the line `args.DatasourceRoots.Add(item);` it shows the dialog.

This is the original Sitecore's class.

```cs
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Sitecore.Pipelines.GetRenderingDatasource
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the datasource location root item
    /// </summary>
    public class GetDatasourceLocation
    {
        public GetDatasourceLocation()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Runs the processor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        public void Process(GetRenderingDatasourceArgs args)
        {
            Assert.IsNotNull(args, "args");
            foreach (string str in new ListString(args.RenderingItem["Datasource Location"]))
            {
                string str1 = str;
                if (str.StartsWith("./", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.ContextItemPath))
                {
                    str1 = string.Concat(args.ContextItemPath, str.Remove(0, 1));
                }
                Item item = args.ContentDatabase.GetItem(str1);
                if (item == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                args.DatasourceRoots.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: The path does exist. Every page on creation gets a folder underneath it named Modules. Still doesn't work. Any other suggestions?